# Formatting multiline docstrings with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Using [sphinx autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html), is there a way to format a first line of a multiline docstring in a special way?

Consider:

```
def whatever():
    """This function does something.

    This really should have a full function definition, but I am too lazy.
    Some more stuff.
    """
```

The html code being generated:

```
<dd>
<p>This function does something.</p>
<p>This really should have a full function definition, but I am too lazy. Some more stuff.</p>
</dd>
```

I want it to be something like:

```
<dd>
<p class='headline'>This function does something.</p>
<p>This really should have a full function definition, but I am too lazy. Some more stuff.</p>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, autodoc doesn't give you very many abilities to mark up the docstrings, especially with regards to adding custom styling to the docstring. There's two ways to get around this I can think of: 1) wrap the first line in `**This function does something**` so it'll be bolded. 2) write a custom sphinx extension which intercepts the docstrings before autodoc has parsed them, and mangle things accordingly.

(I ended up going down the road of option 2 in order to have section headers in my docstrings... here's the [source](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/cloud_sptheme/src/default/cloud_sptheme/ext/autodoc_sections.py) for that extension. It doesn't do what you need, but it might be useful as a starting point, particularly what the `_remove_oneline` function does to module docstrings).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a reasonable way.

Comment: pretty much looking for what you descirebed as option 2 @eli-collins but the link is broken. Could you provide a working one? would be awesome.